# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using 3 tier architecture in my website. Instead of updating in gridview,  I would like to send gridview row values to other page and perform update stuff there. 
Here is the link code in view page.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>  
             <ItemTemplate>
                <a href ='<%#"UpdateCategory.aspx?CategoryID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CategoryID") %>'> <%#Eval("CategoryName") %>  </a>
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

PageLoad event in Update page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int categoryId = 0;
        categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CategoryID"]);
        CategoryBL.GetCategoryByID(categoryId);
    }
```

CategoryBL code:

```
public static DataTable GetCategoryByID(int categoryID)
    {
        Category category = new Category();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Categories] WHERE [CategoryID] = @CategoryID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = categoryID;

        DataTable dt = DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable(cmd);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            category.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CategoryID"]);
            category.CategoryName = dt.Rows[0]["CategoryName"].ToString();
            category.Description = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();

            return category;
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'Object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Getting above mentioned error while returning category in CategoryBL page. Here, I would like to display selected category in update page.

GetRecordsInDataTable Code:

```
public static DataTable GetRecordsInDataTable(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = GetConStr();   

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

             //Logger.Log(ex);
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Update Page:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Category Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CategoryNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you expect `CategoryBL.GetCategoryByID(categoryId);` to do?  you don't assign the return value to anything.  And what is the code for `DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable`?  Based on the posted code, the error is originating in `DbUtility.GetRecordsInDataTable`.

Comment: Note that you're returning `Category` in `CategoryBL.GetCategoryByID`, but the specified return type is `DataTable`.  Try changing the signature to `public static Category GetCategoryByID(int categoryID);`.

Comment: @Tim, I did change. But, I am not able to display those values in update page. The fields are null. When I debug, I could see values being transferred.

Comment: In your page load, you never assign the returned values to anything:  `CategoryBL.GetCategoryByID(categoryId);`  the method will run, and there may be results from it, but that does you no good if you don't assign the results to something.  I'd expect something like `Category category = CategoryBL.GetCategoryByID(categoryId);`.

Comment: Yes. I am returning the value. Thanks Tim. But, I am not able to show in update page. Kindly Look at edited question.

Comment: You're not databinding any values to the controls in your edit.  As currently posted, your code does not do anything with the object returned from the CategoryBL method, and there is no databinding in the posted markup.

Answer (score 0):

Your function waits a DataTable object to return, instead you return a Category Object. You must choose one or another to solve error issue. Change function type to Category or choose to return dt instead.

The choice depends on your handling in Page_Load function. Right now your code is doing nothing, it just creates the object but assigns it nowhere.Have you decide how you will handle the result in update page?

Comment: I just want to display selected gridview row in my Update page where I have added textboxes for each field. You can see textboxes in question posted above. How can I databind ?

Comment: I think this page is exactly what you are looking for http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_binding.htm. Check out Steps (1), (2) and (3) in Declarative Data Binding section